# How can I deal with dynamic class methods using mypy?

Tags: python, mypy

I have a scenario in which I have a class that exists in all cases, but, depending on whether certain external libraries are present, gains some additional functionality. Something like:

```py
try:
    import sqlalchemy as sa

    SA_AVAILABLE = True
except ImportError:
    SA_AVAILABLE = False

class MyClass:
    # Does whatever a MyClass does

if SA_AVAILABLE:
    def my_dynamic_class_func(self) -> sa.orm.Query:
        ...

    setattr(MyClass, "my_dynamic_class_func", my_dynamic_class_func)
```

I then try to use it like so:

```py
foo = MyClass()
query = foo.my_dynamic_class_func() # <--- Uh-oh!
```

All of this is completely valid Python, and will work correctly at runtime. However, the final line will yield a Mypy error in all cases, even if SQLAlchemy is present in the environment, because of its dynamic origin.

Is there a way to correctly type this using Mypy short of just `# type: ignore`ing every call to `my_dynamic_class_func`? I can't simply add a stub for `my_dynamic_class_func`, because it's dependent on a type from SQLAlchemy, which may not be present.

Comment: (just out of curiosity) why `setattr`? You have a string known in advance.

Comment: @SUTerliakov The string is known in advance; the _class_ is not. This example is simplified - in my real-world use case, the class is passed dynamically.

Comment: I mean that you can do just `MyClass.my_dynamic_class_func = my_dynamic_class_func`, `setattr` is only useful when *attribute name* is dynamic, and behavior is the same in other cases. (and to avoid silly criticism without answer: you cannot teach `mypy` about dynamically added attributes, the only possible option you have is in @DeepSpace's answer - perhaps with `AttributeError` instead of `NotImplementedError` to match behavior with unset function, if you consider it more semantically valid; even `mypy` plugin won't help)

Answer (score 0):

I would implement the function anyway and check for the module availability inside the definition. For the return type annotation, we can use string annotations.

```py
class MyClass:
    def my_dynamic_class_func(self) -> 'sa.orm.Query':
        if not SA_AVAILABLE:
            raise NotImplementedError
        ...
```

This also allows for autocompletion to work.